# What does "reproved" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> And unto Sa'rah he said, Behold, I have given thy brother a
>   thousand pieces of silver: behold, he is to thee a covering of the
>   eyes, unto all that are with thee, and with all other: thus she was
>   **reproved**. (Genesis 20:16)

Webster:

> 2 : to express disapproval of (as conduct, actions, or beliefs) : indicate disapprobation of especially by contrast or implication : CENSURE, CONDEMN *it is not for me to reprove popular taste— D.W.Brogan
>
> 3 obsolete   : to prove (as an idea or statement) to be false or erroneous : DISPROVE, REFUTE *reprove my allegation, if you can— Shakespeare
>
> 4 obsolete   : CONVINCE, CONVICT *will reprove the world of sin and of righteousness— Jn 16:8 (Authorized Version)* intransitive verb   : to express rebuke or reproof *came ...to to reprove and exhort— Mary E. Braddon*

Was she proved as a guilty or a righteous?

Comment: That seems to be Genesis 20:16, not 21:16.

Comment: You seem to be reading the KJV, it helps looking at other, more modern version to help your understanding. The [New International Version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+20&version=NIVUK) gives _To Sarah he said, ‘I am giving your brother a thousand shekels[a] of silver. This is to cover the offence against you before all who are with you; you are completely vindicated.’_ which may be clearer?

Answer (score 2):

In this translation of the Bible, it means she was reprimanded:

> **Thus she was reproved**, or *admonished* to be more circumspect for the future
>   <sub>BibleHub: [Matthew Poole's Commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/poole/genesis/20.htm)</sub>

---

It's important to note that [other Bibles](http://biblehub.com/genesis/20-16.htm) translate this passage differently. Instead of "she was reproved", some Bibles have "you are vindicated" (interpreting it as part of what the king was saying; "you" refers to Sarah).

The discrepancies are because the original Hebrew (וְנֹכָחַת) is ambiguous. [BibleHub](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/20-16.htm) has a list of commentaries on the verse, and this point is brought up in a few of them. (I personally found [The Pulpit Commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/genesis/20.htm) the most helpful because it took a neutral stance and outlined several different interpretations.)